# Efficient way to check if IEnumerable contains exactly one element

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable` sequence that is lazy loaded from a `Stream`. It's possible that the steam might be very large (think GBs).

I need to know if the sequence contains exactly one element. Checking if `.Count() == 1` is not efficient because it would enumerate the entire list by reading the complete stream. Using `.Any` is not useful because I need to know if it contains exactly one element, not that it contains any elements.

**Possible solution**

Would `.Take(2).ToList()` and then do a count be the most efficient way to check if a sequence contains exactly one element?

Comment: How about simply doing (assuming `IEnumerable<T> collection`) : `collection.Skip(1).Any()` ?

This would simply test whether there's any number of elements after the first one. And if I'm not mistaken, when the collection is empty, `Skip(1)` would produce an empty enumerator, which would still cause `Any()` to return `false`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked for "efficient", something like this will avoid some of the allocation overhead of LINQ

```cs
int HasOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    // avoid allocating an enumerator if possible.
    if (collection.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(out int actualCount))
    {
        return actualCount == 1;
    }

    // avoid allocating the LINQ IEnumerables for Take().
    using IEnumerator<T> e = collection.GetEnumerator();
    return e.MoveNext() && !e.MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `Take` at most `2` items and then call `Count()`:

```
bool exactlyOne = source.Take(2).Count() == 1;
```

in the worst case we'll read just first two items.